# How to change the size of buttons constrained together depending on screen size of the device in xCode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton, autolayout

I have made an app, with two ViewControllers each displaying different buttons. On the first display controller, there is a Record Sound button, Record label and a stop Recording button. The Record label is 'attached' to the Record sound button and the Stop recording button is 'attached' to the label, all of this using constraints. The issue I am having is that the buttons stay the same size on different devices, causing a cluttered interface or an empty one, depending on the device. I have tried different fixes across the internet but they are only for one individual button, not for groups of buttons.

I would like to learn of a solution that would change the size of the button or stack view depending on the screen size

I also want to learn how to do this with the buttons in multiple stack views in my second ViewController.

Examples:

iPhone 4s/SE: the stop recording button gets cut off in landscape mode. The buttons in both views are two large compared to the size of the screen.

iPads: The buttons are too small compared to the size of the screen.

Here are the fixes I have looked at and tried:

[How can I dynamically set the size of the imageView according to the size of the image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10633720/how-can-i-dynamically-set-the-size-of-the-imageview-according-to-the-size-of-the)

[Adjust button sizes based on screen size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44820114/adjust-button-sizes-based-on-screen-size)

Imgur is rejecting my request so I am not able to upload the image of my problem.

Comment: Check this Answer and apply it to your UIButton in place of imageView. https://stackoverflow.com/a/36702170/4910767

Comment: Ok I'll tell you if it works.

Comment: Hi, sorry, i may have worded my question wrongly. The button frame changes but not the image of the button inside the frame, I wanted to learn how to increase the image of the button inside.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try this, first detecting the size of the current screen in order to modify programmatically the size of your buttons to get a right position.

```
var heightScreen: CGFloat = 0
var widthScreen: CGFloat = 0

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
         super.viewWillAppear(animated)

         let bounds = UIScreen.main.bounds
         self.heightScreen = bounds.size.height //get the height of screen
         self.widthScreen = bounds.size.width //get the width of screen

         //once you have the sizes, you can validate them, for instance..

                //for iPhone 5/5s/SE
            if self.heightScreen==568.0 && self.widthScreen==320.0 { 
                 //here you can set the correct size to your button, depending of the iPhone's screen

                // for iPhone 6/6s/7/7s
            }else if self.heightScreen==667.0 && self.widthScreen==375.0{
                //here....

                //// for iPhone 6s Plus/ 7s Plus
            }else if self.heightScreen==736.0 && self.widthScreen==414.0{
                //here....

                //for iPad Mini / Air
            }else if self.heightScreen==1024.0 && self.widthScreen==768.0{
                //here....

                //iPad Pro
            }else if self.heightScreen==1366.0 && self.widthScreen==1024.0{
                //here....
            }

    }
```

Comment: How do you change the size of the button programatically

Comment: Well, you can do it with this line of code...

buttonName.frame.size = CGSizeMake(100, 50)

where the parameters are CGSizeMake(width, height)